# Does Microsoft Sync needs to loads an entire table on both side to compare?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm not sure to understand well the scenarios for the Microsoft Sync Framework.
I have a huge DB with thousands of lines, identical on the 2 distants SQL servers.

When i synchronize it looks like it retrieves ALL the data to compare..
What about subsequent updates ?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sync process should only be retrieving incremental updates, meaning it should only be getting insert/updates/deletes that occured since the last sync.

are you trying to sync for the first time two databases having the same rows?

if the two databases has identical rows existing by the time you provisioned the databases for synching, Sync Framework has no idea that these existing rows are one and the same. so it will send these same rows to the other database. the change application would fail though on the destination because the rows already exists and this will result to conflicts being raised.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So it means that the first time it wil takes ages... There is no way to start by telling Sync that the 2DB are indentical ?

Comment: unfortunately, none that i know of... when you provision the database, the sync knowledge is empty (they havent synched yet)... if the two DBs are exactly identical, provision one DB, backup, restore db on other server and do a PerformPostRestoreFixup...

Comment: This is important to know...i will try your advice. So there is no way to "serialize" this info in case the program is relaunched between to sync...

Comment: manipulating the sync knowledge is a bit complicated. in your sync community, each copy/replica is identified with a replica id. and the sync knowledge stores what it got from each replica. in an initial sync, this knowledge is of course empty, because they havent synched yet and the sync knowledge only gets built after you sync the first time. the PerformPostRestoreFixup is your quickest workaround without having to delve much into manipulating the sync knowledge yourself.